# How do I count the words that start with an uppercase letter in java?

Tags: java, count, cpu-word, uppercase

I want to make a program that prints the number of words that **START** with an uppercase letter. So I made two strings `str1 = "The deed is done"` and `str2 = "My name is Bond, JAMES Bond"`. For the first string, it printed 1 which is what I wanted. But for the second one it prints 8 instead of 4 because `JAMES` is capitalized.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str1 = "The deed is done";
        String str2 = "My name is Bond, JAMES Bond";

        System.out.println(uppercase(str2));
    }

    public static int uppercase(String str){
        int cnt = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
                cnt++;
        }

        return cnt;
    }
```

That's what I have so far. How would I make it so that the other letters in that word aren't counted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check the *first* character of each *word* in the input string, instead of *all characters* of the input string.

```
public static int uppercase(String str){
    int cnt = 0;

    String[] words = str.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)))
            cnt++;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

A more 'declarative approach' could use a `Stream`

```
public static long uppercase2(String str){
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
            .map(word -> word.charAt(0))
            .filter(Character::isUpperCase)
            .count();
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on why the downvote? I'm eager to improve/correct this answer

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine, I canceled out the downvote, don't really know why it was downvoted.  The only reason I could see is maybe needs more explanation, but I think that warrants a comment here rather than a downvote.

Comment: This one worked actually, not sure why the downvote. Could you explain split works and why you put it in an array?

Comment: @Anonymous: see the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: I would have done it slightly differently.  A `regex` for more than one space and incorporating the `split` into an enhanced `for loop` and not use indices.  But it still worked.  Here's a +1 for solidarity.

Answer (score 1):

```java
      String str1 = "The deed is done";
      String str2 = "My name is Bond, JAMES Bond";

      System.out.println(upperCaseCount(str1));
      System.out.println(upperCaseCount(str2));


     public static int upperCaseCount(String s) {
       int count = 0;
       // append a space to cater for empty string and
       // use regex to split on one or more spaces.
       for (String word : (s + " ").split("\\s+")) {
          if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0))) {
            count++;
          }
       }
       return count;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this is with a regex: `\b[A-Z]` tests for capital letters occurring after a word boundary, so we can just find all matches and count them.

```java
> import java.util.regex.*;
> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]");
> Matcher m = p.matcher("Hi, this is Stack Overflow.");
> int c = 0;
> while(m.find()) { c++; }
> c
3
```